# C++: is it possible to use "universal" pointer to vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std

Good day, SO community!
I am new to C++ and I've ran into a situation in my project, where I have 2 vectors of similar paired data types:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string> firstDataVector
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string> secondDataVector
```

and in one part of the code I need to select and process the vector depending on the external string value. So my question is - is it possible to create a pointer to vector outside of the conditions

```
if (stringValue.find("firstStringCondition"))
{
    //use firstDataVector
}
if (stringValue.find("secondStringCondition"))
{
    //use secondDataVector
}
```

some kind of pDataVector pointer, to which could be assigned the existing vectors (because now project has only two of them, but the vectors count might be increased)

I've tried to create`std::vector<std::string> &pDataVector`  pointer, but it will not work because reference variable must be initialized. So summarizing the question - is it possible to have universal pointer to vector?

Comment: That's a reference, not a pointer. Pointer types are spelled with `*`. And pointers to vectors are exactly like all other (object) pointers; if `x` is a `T`, `&x` is a `T*`.

Comment: `firstDataVector` and `secondDataVector` are of the same type, not of "similar" type as far as we can tell. The first thing that comes to mind would be to extract "use XVector" to a function and just call it with correct argument, no need to create separate pointers.

Comment: make a map std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> then you can lookup the correct std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>  based on the name...

Comment: How about using a `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>::iterartor`?

Comment: What if neither of the `find`s finds a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create a *reference* to one of the `vector`s - and that's certainly possible, but it must be initialized to reference it. You can't defer it.

It's unclear what you want to happen if no match is found in `stringValue` so I've chosen to throw an exception.

> now project has only two of them, but the vectors count might be increased

- Create a `vector` with a mapping between strings that you would like to try to `find` in `stringValue` and then the `vector` you'd like to create a reference to.
- When initializing `pDataVector`, you can call a functor, like a lambda, that returns the reference.
- In the functor, loop over the `vector` holding the strings you'd like to try to `find`, and return the referenced `vector` on the first match you get.

It could look like this:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using vpstype = std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>;

    vpstype firstDataVector{{1, "Hello"}};
    vpstype secondDataVector{{2, "World"}};

    // A vector of the condition strings you want to check keeping the order
    // in which you want to check them.
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<vpstype>>>
        conditions{
            {"firstStringCondition", firstDataVector},
            {"secondStringCondition", secondDataVector},
            // add more mappings here
        };

    // an example stringValue
    std::string stringValue = "ssdfdfsdfsecondStringConditionsdfsfsdf";

    // initialize the vpstype reference:
    auto& pDataVector = [&]() -> vpstype& {
        // loop over all the strings and referenced vpstypes:
        for (auto& [cond, vps] : conditions) {
            if (stringValue.find(cond) != std::string::npos) return vps;
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("stringValue doesn't match any condition string");
    }();

    // and use the result:
    for (auto [i, s] : pDataVector) {
        std::cout << i << ' ' << s << '\n'; // prints "2 world"
    }
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me! Thank you and thanks everyone for a wonderful answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed inintialize references conditionally. Either use a function or lambda that returns the vector you want to reference, or hard code it like below.

```
std::vector<std::string> &pDataVector = 
    (stringValue.find("firstStringCondition") != std::string::npos) ?
        firstDataVector : ((stringValue.find("secondStringCondition") != std::string::npos) ?
            secondDataVector : thirdDataVector);
```

Comment: With _"now project has only two of them, but the vectors count might be increased"_ in mind, this will soon become impractical - but sure, for two it works!

Comment: Thanks, I did not even realize it was a std::string, so I copied the mistake from the OP.